# How to yank lines into the same register then paste into a new buffer?

Tags: vim, script

I can grab lines that contain "lblfig" into the `m` register like this:

```
/lblfig
:let @m=@_ | %g//yank M
```

Then I can paste this collection of lines into a new buffer like this:

```
:new | exe "normal! \"mp"
```

But when I try to run those last two command lines together as one, like this:

```
:let @m=@_ | %g//yank M | new | exe "normal! \"mp"
```

- I only get the first one of the yanked lines pasted into the new buffer.

So how can I do this as a single command-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since the global command allows you to do multiple commands with the `|` between them, the commands *after* the global command are assumed to be *part* of the global command. For example, you intended this:

```
%g//                                    "On every line containing lblfig:
    yank M                              "Yank into register 'M'
                                        "then AFTERWARDS:
            | new | exe "normal! \"mp"  "Paste it into a new buffer.
```

Here is what vim is actually doing:

```
%g//                                    "On every line containing lblfig:
    yank M | new | exe "normal! \"mp"   "Yank into register AND Paste it into a new buffer.
```

The fix is pretty simple. Just wrap your global command in an "execute" statement.

```
let @m=@_ | exe '%g//yank M' | new | exe "normal! \"mp"
```

Comment: Nice. fwiw, I have following in my .vimrc that's essentially doing the same but in yet another way `nnoremap <F3> :redir! @f<cr>:silent g//<cr>:redir! END<cr>:enew!<cr>:put! f<cr>:let @f=@/<cr>:g/^$/d<cr>:let @/=@f<cr>gg`